# Entity Framework Core 6 - Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Roles' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I currently have a problem with EF6 and Fluent API. When inserting into database where model have one to many relationship, I'm getting this error. I've checked some related topics, but I want to keep autoincrement. Model without one to many relationship works perfectly.

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Roles' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__188_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
ClientConnectionId:501a6880-e298-43d5-be69-fcbebacdb15e
Error Number:544,State:1,Class:16
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at WorkIT_Backend.Services.UserService.Create(String username, String password, String role) in C:\Users\Ondřej\Desktop\škola\2022 PRF\WS\OPR3\WorkIT_Backend\WorkIT_Backend\WorkIT_Backend\Services\UserService.cs:line 54
   at WorkIT_Backend.Controllers.UsersController.CreateUser(UserDto user) in C:\Users\Ondřej\Desktop\škola\2022 PRF\WS\OPR3\WorkIT_Backend\WorkIT_Backend\WorkIT_Backend\Controllers\UsersController.cs:line 57
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Model classes

```
public sealed class Role
{
    public long RoleId { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public Role()
    {
        Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }
}
```

```
public class User
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public string? UserName { get; set; }

    public string? PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public long RoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
    }
}
```

OnModelCreating in dbcontext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(q => q.RoleId);
            entity.Property(q => q.RoleId)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.Property(q => q.Name)
                .IsRequired();
            entity.HasIndex(q => q.Name)
                .IsUnique();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(q => q.UserId);
            entity.Property(q => q.UserId)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.Property(q => q.UserName)
                .IsRequired();

            entity.Property(q => q.PasswordHash)
                .IsRequired();

            entity.HasOne(u => u.Role)
                .WithMany(r => r.Users)
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.RoleId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
        });
    }
```

Method in service which is adding the user

```
public async Task<User> Create(string username, string password, string role)
    {
        EnsureNotNull(username, nameof(username));
        EnsureNotNull(password, nameof(password));
        EnsureNotNull(role, nameof(role));

        username = username.ToLower();

        if (_context.Users.Any(q => q.UserName == username))
            throw CreateException($"User {username} already exists.", null);

        var hash = _securityService.HashPassword(password);
        var userRole = await _roleService.GetRole(role);

        var ret = new User {UserName = username, PasswordHash = hash, Role = userRole};

        _context.Users.Add(ret);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return ret;
    }
```

This method for adding roles works perfectly

```
public class RoleService
{
    private readonly WorkItDbContext _context;
    private readonly SecurityService _securityService;


    public RoleService(WorkItDbContext context, SecurityService securityService)
    {
        _context = context;
        _securityService = securityService;
    }

    public async Task<Role> Create(string name)
    {
        EnsureNotNull(name, nameof(name));

        name = name.ToLower();
        if (_context.Roles.Any(q => q.Name == name))
            throw CreateException($"Role {name} already exists.", null);

        var ret = new Role {Name = name};
        _context.Add(ret);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return ret;
    }

    public async Task<List<Role>> GetRoles()
    {
        var roles = await _context.Roles.ToListAsync();
        return roles;
    }

    public async Task<Role> GetRole(string name)
    {
        var role = await _context.Roles.FirstAsync(q => q.Name == name) ??
                   throw CreateException($"Role {name} does not exist.");
        return role;
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(builder.Configuration);
SecurityService securityService = new(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddTransient<WorkItDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<SecurityService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<UserService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<RoleService>();
```

I've different combination of dbcontext methods. I tried auto increment through anotation - identity. I've checked SQL server and autoincrement is alright.

Comment: Are you using a different instance of your DbContext between your role service and user service? This is generally a good idea but the role you get from your role service in your user service isn't being tracked by the instance of DbContext in your user service. This means that when you try to add the new user, it thinks that the role instance is new too and tries to create it again. Since the Id has a value you get that exception. You need to attach the role to the user service's DbContext instance.

Comment: add **WorkItDbContext** as AddScoped life cycle and it wiil work

Comment: Yeah, changing Transient to AddScoped worked. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know why this happened? For your information, just check this Microsoft blog post.


  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships#creating-and-modifying-relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<WorkItDbContext>();
```

to

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<WorkItDbContext>();
```

and then your UserService and RoleService will share a WorkItDbContext, because it will be added as a Scoped service. See [DbContext in dependency injection for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontext-in-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core)